# Populate dynamic modal from list of IDs ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET MVC (using C#/Razor), and for the webapp we're developing, the company I work for is using the extra ViewModel and Service layers approach to MVC.

High-level outline of the simple task I want to have happen: A data table (jQuery DataTables plugin) has in it a column that displays a number of "Tests" associated with the row's "Event".  This # tests value is a link that opens a modal to display details of all those tests associated with that Event.

Complications: in the View for the Event page, I'm populating the other cells in the data table as such:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @*link to open Tests Details modal using item.Tests list object property as display*@
            </td>
            <td class="bento-grid-row-level-actions" style="text-align:right">
                <a href="#triggerModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn transparent"  onclick="setModalItems('@item.Id','@item.Name')"><i class="icon-flag"></i></a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn transparent"><i class="icon-list "></i></a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn transparent"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn transparent"><i class="icon-remove "></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

In the EventViewModel, the Tests property that I desire to call with item.Tests is currently a collection of TestDetailViewModels (so a ViewModel containing a property that's a list of ViewModels) derived from the EventService.  My initial hope was that this would streamline displaying the Test details in the modal when the time came in the Event view.

My problem is -- i think -- simple: I'm not sure how to access and iterate through this collection of Tests in the  modal chunk in the Event View class:

```
<div id="testsModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3>Tests</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
@*Display info from the collection of TestDetailsViewModels here somehow*@
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

or how to ultimately turn that collection of TestDetailsViewModels into a modal within the Event View.  Any direction or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understood, you already have proper data on your page, in this case you can render all items by

```
@Html.Partial("PartilViewName", item.Tests)
```

into `div` with `display:none;` and when you will click by link, show proper modal popup

i.e. the PartilViewName.cshtml will be like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<TestDetailsViewModels>


 <div class="testsModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3>Tests</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           //Display info from the collection of TestDetailsViewModels here
       }
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```